# can't create more than 1 group lifecycle policy

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api

I can't add more than 1 group lifecycle policy. is it something i missed or i'm wrong ?

There is an existing policy for my tenant. When I tried creating a new policy for the same tenant, I got the following error.

```
Error : Tenant already has maximum allowed 1 policy
Exception Message : Error in validating lifecycle manangement policy
Exception Code : MaxExpirationPoliciesCountReached
Exception Type : Microsoft.Graph.ServiceException
```

.

```
"error": {
"code": "MaxExpirationPoliciesCountReached",
"message": "Error in validating lifecycle manangement policy. Error: Tenant already has maximum allowed 1 policy(s).",
"innerError": {
"request-id": "1f557bc9-1343-4ffc-a7db-92897d491610",
"date": "2019-03-05T08:58:43"
```

In the Response body of List groupLifecyclePolicies document, the value is an Array []. Is it possible to create more than one policies for a tenant.

also ref : https://github.com/microsoftgraph/microsoft-graph-docs/issues/4013

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a known limitation of AAD. From the documentation, [Configure the expiration policy for Office 365 groups](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/users-groups-roles/groups-lifecycle):

> Currently only one expiration policy can be configured for Office 365 groups on a tenant.